# How to make dynamic modal window depending on element id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a website with a catalog. What I want to do, is a modal window, that opens when I click on product card and has other information and photos about product.I have already made special id's for all products, but I can't make a script. Is there easy solution for this ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uTof.jpg)

Also my full code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Incognitus/pen/QBMPWL)

```js
$(".clothes_js").click(function() {
  $(".cl-item").hide();
  $(".clothes").show("fast");
  $(".boots").show("fast");
});

$(".hzt_js").click(function() {
  $(".cl-item").hide();
  $(".cl-item.ph").show("fast");
  $(".cl-item.sl").show("fast");
  $(".cl-item.tr").show("fast");
});

$(".pled_js").click(function() {
  $(".cl-item").hide();
  $(".cl-item.pled").show("fast");
});

function catalog() {
    document.getElementById("cg").style.display = "grid";
    document.getElementById("cl").style.display = "grid";
    document.getElementById("back-btn").style.visibility = "visible";
};

$(".back-btn").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".cg-dummy").offset().top},
        'slow');
});

// FLickity Start

$('.slideshow').flickity({
  // options
  cellAlign: 'center',
  contain: true,
  wrapAround: true, 
  autoPlay: 5000, 
  prevNextButtons: false,
  cellSelector: '.ss-item'
});
```

```css
/*----------------------------------------*\
 #ESSENTIALS
\*----------------------------------------*/

:root {
 --dark-blue: #34495e;
 --green: #27ae60;
 --shadow: 0 0 30px 1px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
 --b_green: 3px solid var(--green);
 --orange: #e67e22;
 --gradient : linear-gradient(to bottom right, #00e5ff, #2ecc71);
 --gradient_shadow: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3))
}


/*------------------
 !COLORS
------------------*/

.blue         { background-color: #1078A4; }

.biruza       { background-color: #00939A; }

.siren        { background-color: #C13C8D; }

.malina       { background-color: #E76F77; }

.corall       { background-color: #E44440; }

.an-dark-blue { background-color: #24204A; }

.olive        { background-color: #635836; }

.baklajan    { background-color: #503944; }

.grey         { background-color: grey;    }

.cream { 
 background-color: #E9C4AA;
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.gradient { 
 background: var(--gradient);
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.white {
 background-color: white;
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.yellow {
 background-color: #FFCE65;
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}


/*------------------
 !ANIMATIONS
------------------*/

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}
@keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}


/*------------------
 !MAIN
------------------*/

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 /*font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;*/
 text-align: center;
}

html, body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}

.dummy {
 visibility: hidden;
}






/*----------------------------------------*\
 #ESSENTIALS
\*----------------------------------------*/

.navbar {
 position             : relative;
 top                  : 0;
 display              : grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 justify-items        : center;
 align-items          : center;
 width                : 100%;
 padding              : 10px;
 background-color     : var(--dark-blue);
}

.home-btn a img {
 margin    : 0;
 border    : 3px solid white;
 min-width : 180px;
 min-height: 80px;
}

tr > td {
 padding    : 3px 0;
 text-align : left;
 color      : var(--green);
 font-weight: bold;
}

td img {
 float       : right;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width       : 20px;
 height      : 20px;
}


/*------------------
 !SLIDESHOW
------------------*/

.slideshow {
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 position  : relative;
}

.ss-item {
 width       : 100%;
 height      : 80vh;
 margin-right: 0;
 background  : var(--green);
 font-size   : 1.25em;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(1) {
 background         : url(../img/ss1.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(2) {
 background         : url(../img/ss2.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(3) {
 background         : url(../img/ss3.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(4) {
 background         : url(../img/ss4.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(5) {
 background         : url(../img/ss5.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item__text {
 position: absolute;
 left    : 50px;
 bottom  : 50px;
 width   : 90%;
}

.ss-item__h1 {
 margin : 0;
 padding: 10px;
 float  : left;
 display: inline-block;
 color  : white/*var(--green)*/;
 /*background: var(--dark-blue);*/
}

.ss-item__p {
 margin      : 0;
 padding     : 10px;
 width       : 80%;
 float       : left;
 clear       : left;
 display     : inline-block;
 color       : white/*var(--green)*/;
 text-align  : left;
 /*background: var(--dark-blue);*/
}


.slideshow .flickity-page-dots {
 bottom : 0.5em;
 opacity: 1;
}

.slideshow .flickity-page-dots .dot {
 width     : 10px;
 height    : 10px; 
 background: #ccc;
 border    : 2px solid transparent;
}

.slideshow .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected {
 background: #76ff03;
}


/*------------------
 !INFO
------------------*/

.info {
 display           :grid;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
 margin            : 20px;
 box-shadow        : var(--shadow);
}

.info__text {
 background  : var(--dark-blue);
 color       : var(--green);
 text-align  : center;
 font-size   : 1.2em;
 border-top  : 3px solid var(--green);
 margin      : 0;
 padding     : 20px;
 /*box-shadow: var(--shadow);*/
}

.info__map iframe {
 height: 100%;
 width : 100%;
}






/*----------------------------------------*\
 #CATALOG STUFF
\*----------------------------------------*/


/*------------------
 !DUMMY
------------------*/


.cg-dummy {
 position           : relative;
 width              : 100%;
 height             : 500px;
 background         : url(../img/catalog.jpg);
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-color   : #000;
 box-shadow         : var(--shadow);
 box-sizing         : border-box;
 display            : -webkit-flex;
 display            : -moz-flex;
 display            : -ms-flex;
 display            : -o-flex;
 display            : flex;
 justify-content    : center;
 align-items        : center;
 margin             : 30px auto;
 cursor             : pointer;
 transition         : opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}

.cg-dummy:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.cg-dummy h1 {
 font-weight: bold;
 color      : var(--green);
 padding    : 10px;
 border     : 3px solid var(--green);
 transition : opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.cg-dummy:hover h1 { opacity: .7; }


/*------------------
 !CATEGORIES
------------------*/

.cg {
 display: none;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(382px, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 margin: 0 20px;
}


.cg-h1 {
 display      : none;
 text-align   : center;
 font-size    : 2.5em;
 color        : var(--green);
 margin       : 20px auto; 
 cursor       : pointer;
 padding      : 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

 
.cg-item {
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid var(--green);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8)/*var(--shadow)*/;
}

.cg-item:focus {
 border-right: var(--b_green);
 border-left: var(--b_green);
 border-top: var(--b_green);
}

.cg-item h1 {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 2.3em;
 color: var(--green);
}

.cg-item:nth-child(1) h1::before {
 content: "";
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: -70px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   background: url(../svg/fashion.svg);
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.cg-item:nth-child(2) h1::before {
 content: "";
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: -70px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 background: url(../svg/dish.svg);
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.cg-item:nth-child(3) h1::before {
 content: "";
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: -70px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 background: url(../svg/armchair.svg);
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.back-btn {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 2px solid var(--green);
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 z-index: 160;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: var(--orange);
 visibility: hidden;
}


/*------------------
 !CATALOG
------------------*/

.cl {
 display: none;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 340px);
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 justify-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-content: center;
 margin: 20px 0;
}

.cl::after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.cl-item {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 70px) 70px 15px;
   grid-template-columns: 320px;
   box-shadow: var(--shadow);
   width: 320px;
   height: 364px;
   /*float: left;*/
}

.cl-item::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cl-item img {
 grid-row: 1/5;
 display: block;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
 object-fit: fill;
}

.cl-item__info {
 grid-row: 6/7;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

 .cl-item__color {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
  color: white /*var(--orange)*/;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
 }

 .cl-item__size {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--orange);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
 }

.cl-item p {
 /*display: inline;*/
 grid-row: 5/6;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 background-color: var(--dark-blue);
 border-top: 4px solid var(--green);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 19.2px;
 color: var(--green);
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}


.clothes img, .boots img {
  /*width: 70%;*/
  object-fit: contain;
}






/*----------------------------------------*\
 #ESSENTIALS
\*----------------------------------------*/


/*------------------
 !MEDIA
------------------*/


@media (min-width: 1280px) {

 .info {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }

 .info__text {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid var(--green);
 }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {

 body {
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 .ss-item__text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom    : 30px;
  left    : 30px;
  width   : 90%;
  font-size: .8em;
 }
 .info {
  display           :grid;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr;
  margin            : 20px;
  box-shadow        : var(--shadow);
 }

 .cg {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  margin: 0;
 }
 

 .cg-item h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
 }
 
 .cg-item:nth-child(3) h1::before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: -60px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: url(../svg/armchair.svg);
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
 }
 
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
 .navbar {
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
   }
  
   .dummy {
     display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 361px) {

 .navbar-number {
  margin: 20px auto;
 }

 .cg-dummy {
  height: 200px;
 }

 .ss-item__text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom  : 30px;
  left    : 20px;
  width   : 90%;
  font-size: .7em;
 }

 .cg-item {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  font-size: 1.2em;
 }

 .cg-item img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

 }

 .cl-item {
  margin: 20px auto;
 }



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>TextileToday</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=9">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flickity.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/myScript.js?v=9"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar">

   
   <div class="info-tb  dummy">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt=""></td>
        <td>84955100075</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
       <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt=""></td>
        <td>@Textile2day</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt=""></td>
        <td>info.torgservice@bk.ru</td> 
      </tr>

    </table>

   </div>


   <div class="home-btn">
    <a href="#home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
   

   <div class="info-tb__header">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="svg/telephone.svg" alt=""></td>
        <td>84955100075</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img src="svg/instagram.svg" alt=""></td>
        <td>@Textile2day</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img src="svg/email.svg" alt=""></td>
        <td>info.torgservice@bk.ru</td> 
      </tr>

    </table>

   </div>


 </nav>
 





 <section class="slideshow">


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Новое поколение</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Велсофт — это синтетика нового поколения. Ткань называют также микрофиброй. Страна рождения – Япония. Именно здесь, на островах высоких технологий, в 1976 году был разработан способ изготовления уникальных, ультратонких волокон, диаметр которых не превышает 0,06 мм</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Комфорт</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Велсофт создан для домашнего комфорта и уюта. Её пушистый, мягкий ворс напоминает велюр, но отличается особой шелковистостью и нежностью. Изделия из этого материала дарят и взрослым, и детям ощущения особого домашнего тепла и покоя</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Дышащая ткань</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Наличие достаточно длинного и воздушного ворса, необыкновенно тёплого и приятного на ощупь, приводит к тому, что изделие почти мгновенно достигает температуры человеческого тела, в последующем сохраняя полученное тепло. Одежда из велсофта препятствует перегреву даже в очень тёплом помещении</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Безопасность</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Велсофт производят в полном соответствии с нормами международной системы сертификации и тестирования изделий из текстиля Эко Текс, что делает его пригодным для производства домашней и детской одежды</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Гипоалергенность</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Микрофибра — гипоаллергенная ткань, состоящая из полимерных и натуральных волокон, в том числе нейлона, полиэстера, хлопка или вискозы. Ткань широко применяется при производстве одежды, мебели, в промышленности. В ее основе — ультратонкие волокна, в 10 раз меньше диаметра волокна натурального шелка</p>
   </div>
  </div>


 </section>





 
 <div class="cg-dummy" id="cg-dummy" onclick="catalog()">
  <h1 id="dummy__h1">Каталог</h1>
 </div> 
 

 <div class="cg" id="cg">


  <button class="cg-item  сlothes_js">
   <h1>Одежда</h1>
  </button>


  <button class="cg-item  hzt_js">
   <h1>Хозтовары</h1>
  </button>


  <button class="cg-item  pled_js">
   <h1>Товары для дома</h1>
  </button>


 </div>


 <div class="back-btn" id="back-btn"><img src="svg/upload.svg" alt=""></div>


 <div class="cl" id="cl">
  
  <!--------------------------
   ТОВАРЫ ДЛЯ ДОМА
  -------------------------->

  <!------------
   DPLED
  ------------->

  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A000">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled1.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color cream">Кремовый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
    </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A001">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color blue">Голубой</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A002">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled3.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color biruza">Бирюза</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A003">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled4.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color siren">Сирень</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A004">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled5.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color malina">Малина</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A005">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled6.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color corall">Коралл</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A006">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled7.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color malina">Малина</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A007">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled8.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color corall">Коралл</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A008">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled9.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color biruza">Бирюза</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A009">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled10.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color siren">Сирень</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A010">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled11.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color cream">Кремовый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A011">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled12.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color blue">Голубой</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A012">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled13.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color corall">Коралл</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A013">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled14.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color malina">Малина</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A014">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled15.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color blue">Голубой</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A015">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled16.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color siren">Сирень</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A016">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled17.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color biruza">Бирюза</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A017">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled18.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color cream">Кремовый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <!------------
   OPLED
  ------------->

  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A018">
   <img src="img/opled/opled1.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color an-dark-blue">Темно-Голубой</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A019">
   <img src="img/opled/opled2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color olive">Оливковый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A020">
   <img src="img/opled/opled3.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color baklajan">Баклажан</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A021">
   <img src="img/opled/opled4.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color baklajan">Баклажан</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>




 <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
 <script src="js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- (.cl-item>im id="0000"g.ph$+p{Lorem ipsum dolor.})*4 -->
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't make a script"?

Answer (score 0):

A crude and simple way to do it would be to make a simple div. Style it the way you want a modal to appear. Adjust z-index accordingly. Set display as none.

When the product is clicked, set the innerHTML of the div with the details you want, and set the display as block.

You can also integrate bootstrap modal, but try to code a basic sample yourself to learn how it works.